# Multiple Regression in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to do a simple regression in R using the following syntax:

[image: Syntax]

Unfortunately, R keeps giving me warnings and the summary is not possible:

[image: Warnings]

I can't find out the problem. The data includes more than just the 11 predictors mentioned in the syntax.

Thank you!
Melanie

Comment: Hey, Melixy13! That is not actually a problem or an error. These are just warning messages. Also, next time when you will ask question on Stackoverflow, read this article, please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The message says that the response is a factor, maybe a Poisson or negative binomial regression is better suited for the problem (`glm`). Note that the second message says pretty much the same thing, the residuals are computed with a subtraction, `resp - pred`.

Comment: Try `class(PTBS_phq_imputed$phq_sum_last)` if the answer is a "factor" there's your problem as @Rui points out.  What to do about it depends on what sort of variable it really is.  If you believe you can treat it like a number because it is a "sum" and has the properties of a number then `PTBS_phq_imputed$phq_sum_last <- as.numeric(as.character(PTBS_phq_imputed$phq_sum_last))` should solve it if it is truly a factor then follow @Rui's advice and choose a different model like `glm`

Comment: For a better explanation make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11570343) of your data using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

This answer partially consists of comments in the original question.

---

That is not an error. It's a warning message (it differs from error). It's generated because you attempt to use `lm()` for a factor-type response variable. Operations like + and - does not work on factor, hence the message "-" not meaningful for factors.

If the response is truly a categorical variable, `lm()` might not be the right way to go to model it. Alternatives in this situation:

- `glm()`: Binary logistic regression, Poisson regression, negative binomial regression
- `MASS::polr()`: Ordinal logistic regression
- `nnet::multinom()`: Multinomial logistic regression
- and many more others.

Please research the corresponding methods before actually using it.

If the response is actually NOT a categorical variable, you will want to look further why it is coded as  a factor, and turn it to numeric first.